# Where does vmstat get it's "used memory" statistic from?

Tags: linux, memory, monitoring

If you run `vmstat -s`, it displays statistics about your system.  I am wondering what it does to calculate the `used memory` statistic (highlighted below).  This is not a statistic that I can find in `/proc/meminfo`.

```
user@machine:# vmstat -s
      7483816 K total memory
      **4740624 K used memory**
      3619096 K active memory
       800388 K inactive memory
      2743192 K free memory
       220624 K buffer memory
      1989008 K swap cache
       901116 K total swap
            0 K used swap
       901116 K free swap *snip*
```

How does `vmstat` get that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vmstat` gets the virtual memory stat from `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/vmstat`, and processor related info from `/proc/stat`:

```
% strace -fe open vmstat -s
...
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY)            = 4
open("/proc/vmstat", O_RDONLY)          = 5
...
```

---

For used memory, from https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/sysinfo.c#L772:

```
if (mem_used < 0)     
  mem_used = kb_main_total - kb_main_free;   
kb_main_used = (unsigned long)mem_used;
```

Comment: That's helpful, but there is no one entry in that file that matches the output.  It must be using data from `/proc/vmstat` to calculate "used memory".  The question is what data...?

Comment: @Questionmark Check the edited `strace` output, it gets the data from relevant sources, and print the output in pretty form after doing some calculations. The used memory is from `/proc/meminfo` btw.

Comment: +1 I get that part.  Now my remaining question is:  What calculations does `vmstat` do to get the "used memory"?

Comment: @Questionmark Here https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/vmstat.c

Comment: The answer is in `/proc/sysinfo.c`.  Line 772: `mem_used = kb_main_total - kb_main_free;`  Total - Used (doh!).  Add that to your answer, and I can accept it.  :)